# Change jQuery options later on in a script

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, grid, widget, draggable

I have a jQuery section of my javascript file that says :

```
$('#'+window.currentID.last()).draggable(
        {
        cursor: "move",
            drag: function(){
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            window.xPos = offset.left;
            window.yPos = offset.top;
        },
         revert : function(event, ui) {
            $(this).data("draggable").originalPosition = {
                top : 0,
                left : 0
            };
            // return boolean
            return !event;
        }   
    });
```

This is called on document load so my div automatically becomes draggable when the page has loaded (Which is exactly what i wanted).. but i have a button on the page which says "Snap to grid" and upon clicking the button i wanted to add an option to the jQuery widget.

My initial thoughts were that this would work :

```
('#btn-snap').click(function() {
$('#'+window.currentID.last()).draggable({ grid: [10, 10] });
});
```

But this simply doesn't do anything.. I could do with a piece of code to go inside my click event that will simply add the `grid: [10, 10]` option into the `$().draggable`.

Does anybody have any ideas because I'm going a little insane here? :D

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please create a fiddle ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4GnZV/

Comment: Its working in the fiddle?! Okay so now I'm confused even more! I have the exact same click event in my code and window.currentID.last just returns the id of the div clicked on before the button (in the case of the fiddle - dragMe). Hmmmmm

Comment: Yes it is perfectly working in fiddle, you should check up your code once again !

Comment: Calling `.draggable({ grid: [10, 10] })` is **not** an option setter, it's a call to `initialise()`. It *may* behave like a setter but is not guaranteed to. The common widget option setter is `.draggable("option", "grid", [10, 10])`